How do I change email body to SMS body in wordpress?
I have a code that sends woocommerce partial payments email reminders.
I want to use same email code for SMS reminders. Already the email code below sends emails perfectly well, but i also want to send SMS reminders. Here is the code
// email body
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit ; // Exit if accessed directly
}
?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ) ; ?>

<?php if ( $payment_order->has_status( 'pending' ) ) : ?>

    <p>
        <?php
        /* translators: 1: product title with installment number 2: payment number */
        printf( wp_kses_post( __( 'Hi, <br>Your Invoice for %1$s from payment #%2$s has been generated. The Payment details are as follows', 'sumopaymentplans' ) ), wp_kses_post( $product_title_with_installment ), esc_html( $payment->get_payment_number() ) ) ;
        ?>
    </p>

<?php endif ; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $payment_order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) ; ?>

<h2>
    <?php
    /* translators: 1: payment number */
    printf( wp_kses_post( __( 'Payment #%s', 'sumopaymentplans' ) ), esc_html( $payment->get_payment_number() ) ) ;
    ?>
</h2>

<table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'sumopaymentplans' ) ; ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'sumopaymentplans' ) ; ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'sumopaymentplans' ) ; ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        echo wp_kses_post( wc_get_email_order_items( $payment_order, array(
            'show_sku'      => $sent_to_admin,
            'show_image'    => false,
            'image_size'    => array( 32, 32 ),
            'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
            'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin,
        ) ) ) ;
        ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <?php
        $text_align  = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left' ;
        $item_totals = $payment_order->get_order_item_totals() ;

        if ( $item_totals ) {
            $i = 0 ;
            foreach ( $item_totals as $total ) {
                $i++ ;
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ) ; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : '' ; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total[ 'label' ] ) ; ?></th>
                    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ) ; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : '' ; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total[ 'value' ] ) ; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<p>
    <?php
    /* translators: 1: payment url 2: next payment date */
    printf( wp_kses_post( __( 'Please make the payment using the payment link %1$s on or before <strong>%2$s</strong>', 'sumopaymentplans' ) ), '<a href="' . esc_url( $payment_order->get_checkout_payment_url() ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'pay', 'sumopaymentplans' ) . '</a>', esc_html( _sumo_pp_get_date_to_display( $payment->get_prop( 'next_payment_date' ), 'email' ) ) ) ;
    ?>
</p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email ) ; ?>

How do I convert the emal body above and insert it into the SMS body below?
// send sms
<?php

$to = $phone;
$message = "body";
wp_sms_send( $to, $msg, true);

?>

It is basically converting the email php to an SMS body. This is what I have done so far. Not sending message.
// send sms
<?php

$to = $phone;
$message = "<?php if ( $payment_order->has_status( 'pending' ) ) : ?>

            <?php
            /* translators: 1: product title with installment number 2: payment number */
            printf( wp_kses_post( __( 'Hi, <br>Your Invoice for %1$s from payment #%2$s has been generated. The Payment details are as follows', 'sumopaymentplans' ) ), wp_kses_post( $product_title_with_installment ), esc_html( $payment->get_payment_number() ) ) ;
            ?>
            
            <?php endif ; ?>

            <?php
            /* translators: 1: payment number */
            printf( wp_kses_post( __( 'Payment #%s', 'sumopaymentplans' ) ), esc_html( $payment->get_payment_number() ) ) ;
            ?>

            <?php
            /* translators: 1: payment url 2: next payment date */
            printf( wp_kses_post( __( 'Please make the payment using the payment link %1$s on or before <strong>%2$s</strong>', 'sumopaymentplans' ) ), '<a href="' . esc_url( $payment_order->get_checkout_payment_url() ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'pay', 'sumopaymentplans' ) . '</a>', esc_html( _sumo_pp_get_date_to_display( $payment->get_prop( 'next_payment_date' ), 'email' ) ) ) ;
            ?>";
wp_sms_send( $to, $msg, true);

?>


Have you signed up with an sms gateway, and configured it? Unlike email, it's not free

@ADyson Yes. am signed up to a gateway. using WP SMS to send messages

$message = "<?php if ... makes little sense. You are in a PHP context already. Do it the other way around - start with the if, and then inside, assign / append to $message. Use sprintf instead of printf. And then pass the correct variable to wp_sms_send.
